# I need help on getting a preferred format for the text i pulled out with a webscraper. (Complete Beginner)

Tags: python, web-scraping, text-formatting

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


def scraper(url):
    url = "https://www.folhape.com.br/economia/preco-da-gasolina-cai-apos-duas-semanas-de-alta-nos-postos-diz-anp/280763/"
    req = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")
    title = soup.find("title")
    subtitle = soup.find("h2")
    text = soup.find("article", class_="grid_8 prefix_2 textoArea").text
    return (title.text, subtitle.text, text)


string1 = scraper("https://www.folhape.com.br/economia/preco-da-gasolina-cai-apos-duas-semanas-de-alta-nos-postos-diz-anp/280763/")
print(string1)
```

This is the code I am running and this is the output

```
('Preço da gasolina cai após duas semanas de alta nos postos, diz ANP - Folha PE', 'Diesel tem queda pela 23ª semana consecutiva', '\nO preço da gasolina nos postos de combustíveis caiu nesta semana, de acordo com levantamento feito pela Agência Nacional de preços (ANP). O valor médio por litro passou de R$ 5,67 para R$ 5,63, recuo de 0,7% ou quatro centavos. É a primeira queda após duas semanas seguidas de avanço na bomba.\nNo início deste mês, a Petrobras reduziu o preço da gasolina nas refinarias: o valor médio por litro caiu para R$ 2,52, uma redução de cerca de R$ 0,14 ou 5,3%. Somente neste ano foram quatro reduções nas refinarias.\nJá o preço do litro do diesel caiu pela 23ª semana consecutiva: foi de R$ 4,95 para R$ 4,94 . O litro do etanol também teve recuo nesta semana: passou de R$ 3,93 por litro para R$ 3,87.\nLeia também• Inflação mensal na Argentina desacelera e atinge 6% em junho• "Inflação das férias" sobe quase o triplo da média e passa de 5%, com cinemas e lanches mais caros• Desenrola, programa de renegociação de dívida, começa na segunda. Veja guia preparado pelos bancos\nApós a última redução anunciada no preço da gasolina pela Petrobras, o preço do petróleo no mercado internacional vem subindo. A cotação do Brent, referência internacional, desde o início deste mês subiu de US$ 74,90, chegou a mais de US$ 81 e hoje está em US$ 79,7.\nCom isso, o preço vendido pela Petrobras no Brasil está menor em relação ao exterior. Dados da Abicom, que reúne os importadores, apontam que o litro vendido pela estatal está nesta sexta-feira 16% abaixo das cotações internacionais.\nReportar ErroVeja tambémConcursoBNDES fará concurso para níveis médio e superior com foco em diversidade e inclusãoEconomiaMercado prevê PIB de 2,24% este anoREFORMA TRIBUTÁRIAReforma Tributária: "Quanto mais exceções tiverem, menos vai funcionar", diz HaddadNEGÓCIOSH&M anuncia planos para abrir lojas no Brasil em 2025BRASILAtividade econômica tem queda de 2% no mês de maio, aponta "prévia" do PIB')
```

Now here is the output from the same code with only, return (text).

```
O preço da gasolina nos postos de combustíveis caiu nesta semana, de acordo com levantamento feito pela Agência Nacional de preços (ANP). O valor médio por litro passou de R$ 5,67 para R$ 5,63, recuo de 0,7% ou quatro centavos. É a primeira queda após duas semanas seguidas de avanço na bomba.
No início deste mês, a Petrobras reduziu o preço da gasolina nas refinarias: o valor médio por litro caiu para R$ 2,52, uma redução de cerca de R$ 0,14 ou 5,3%. Somente neste ano foram quatro reduções nas refinarias.
Já o preço do litro do diesel caiu pela 23ª semana consecutiva: foi de R$ 4,95 para R$ 4,94 . O litro do etanol também teve recuo nesta semana: passou de R$ 3,93 por litro para R$ 3,87.
Leia também• Inflação mensal na Argentina desacelera e atinge 6% em junho• "Inflação das férias" sobe quase o triplo da média e passa de 5%, com cinemas e lanches mais caros• Desenrola, programa de renegociação de dívida, começa na segunda. Veja guia preparado pelos bancos
Após a última redução anunciada no preço da gasolina pela Petrobras, o preço do petróleo no mercado internacional vem subindo. A cotação do Brent, referência internacional, desde o início deste mês subiu de US$ 74,90, chegou a mais de US$ 81 e hoje está em US$ 79,7.
Com isso, o preço vendido pela Petrobras no Brasil está menor em relação ao exterior. Dados da Abicom, que reúne os importadores, apontam que o litro vendido pela estatal está nesta sexta-feira 16% abaixo das cotações internacionais.
Reportar ErroVeja tambémConcursoBNDES fará concurso para níveis médio e superior com foco em diversidade e inclusãoEconomiaMercado prevê PIB de 2,24% este anoREFORMA TRIBUTÁRIAReforma Tributária: "Quanto mais exceções tiverem, menos vai funcionar", diz HaddadNEGÓCIOSH&M anuncia planos para abrir lojas no Brasil em 2025BRASILAtividade econômica tem queda de 2% no mês de maio, aponta "prévia" do PIB
```

so, no `"\n"` and random commas throughout. Can anynone help me with this?

well I tried to separate the texts like this `return(title.text),(subtitle.text),(text)` and also tried to isolate the text like this, `return(title.text, subtitle.text),(text)`. Neither of these approaches worked.

Comment: I don't understand. You're returning a tuple of 3 elements from the function. So instead of `print(string1)` do for example `print(*string1, sep='\n')`

Answer (score 1):

You could use **replace** in any occurance of "\n" in the response text.
Like this:

```
"test\ntest".replace('\n', ' ')
```

results in:

```
"test test"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def scraper(url):
    url = "https://www.folhape.com.br/economia/preco-da-gasolina-cai-apos-duas-semanas-de-alta-nos-postos-diz-anp/280763/"
    req = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")
    title = soup.find("title").text
    subtitle = soup.find("h2").text
    text = soup.find("article", class_="grid_8 prefix_2 textoArea").text.strip()
    text = " ".join(text.split())  # Remove extra whitespace characters
    text = text.replace(",", "")  # Remove commas
    return title, subtitle, text

string1 = scraper("https://www.folhape.com.br/economia/preco-da-gasolina-cai-apos-duas-semanas-de-alta-nos-postos-diz-anp/280763/")
print(string1)
```